# Error: Cannot match any routes: 'player-profile;userID=2'

Tags: angular

I have the following template expression:

```
 [routerLink]="['player-profile',{userID:activity.user.id}]"
```

And the following definition in app.routing.ts:

```
{path:'player-profile/:userID', component: PlayerProfileComponent},
```

Why clicking the routerLink returns the following error:

```
Error: Cannot match any routes: 'player-profile;userID=2'
```

?

Angular 2 RC.5 + new Router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use just

```
[routerLink]="['player-profile', activity.user.id]"
```

the object is used for query parameters. For route parameters the position is significant. No need to pass the name.